# Trying to GET all "classes" documents from Mongo DB with user ObjectIDs that match the user ObjectID of the user who created them

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a Sales Portal with the MERN stack and I am trying to GET all the documents in a MongoDB collection called "classes" that were created by the user that is currently logged in. To do this, I am trying to retrieve all "classes" that have the same "user" ObjectID.

Here is a sample "classes" document:
[classes document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dvi1.png)

Here is my controller:

```
// @desc    Fetch classes made by logged in user
// @route   GET /api/classes/
// @access  Public

const getClassesByUserId = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const classes = await Class.find({ user: req.user.id });

    if (classes) {
      res.json(classes);
    } else {
      res.status(404);
      throw new Error('Classes not found');
    }
  });
```

Am I using an inferior method? Am I missing a variable declaration? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?? One thing i wouldn't do is throwing an error, `res.status(404);` is just enough. Well you are not responding if no classes found, you should do `res.status(404).send();`

Comment: The problem is I need to fetch only the documents in the "classes" collection that were created by the logged-in user. I want to GET the documents that have the "user" ObjectID that matches the logged in user's ObjectID.

Comment: Well i understand what you want, but what problem do you have with your code?  Do you not get the results expected? What do you get then?

Comment: I am not sure that I am using the correct query structure or defining my values properly to execute the request properly. Here's a look at my "listUserClasses" action:
`export const listUserClasses = user => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: CLASS_USER_LIST_REQUEST });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/classes?user=${user}`, config);`